# Как правильно выбрать элемент

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно обратится к классу "serv_rate" через id?

```
<div id="rating_1">
    <span class="serv_rate"></span>
    <span class="serv_rate"></span>
    <span class="serv_rate"></span>
    <span class="serv_rate"></span>
    <span class="serv_rate"></span>
</div>

mainClass = $('.serv_rate');
var idElem = $("#rating_" + 1, mainClass);
idElem.addClass('smallstar');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#rating_1 .serv_rate').addClass('smallstar');
```

Comment: Спасибо! А  в случае, если последняя цифра в айди будет меняться, как правильно делать?

Comment: @wao138 '#rating_1 .serv_rate' - строка, решение вашего вопроса очевидно

Comment: @kolpak, к примеру там не 1, а некая переменная id. Как тогда?

Comment: @wao138, вы со строками работать умеете?

Comment: @wao138, $('#rating_' + id + ' .serv_rate')